# How could I use 40lb Propane tanks in a residential hook up?

Tags: heating, stove, propane

I have two 100 gallon tanks from suburban propane but end up using so little, that I am charged approx $5.30 per gallon. I am reasonably sure that I could use two 40lb tanks and do the legwork myself without much inconvenience but I have no idea if such a setup is advisable or even possible.

Right now, the propane is only used in my stove/range and as a rarely used backup to my electric heat.

Comment: Legal questions are considered off-topic here: http://diy.stackexchange.com/faq#note-the-following-are-considered-off-topic

Comment: @NiallC. I made some edits. It would still give me a good foot hold of info without going against the rules.

Answer (score 1):

Call suburban, tell them that you don't want the tanks any more.

Make sure you are present when they unhook so there is no damage to your connection.

I recommend that you use a pair of tanks, so that there is always a spare on hand. One is disconnected and capped.  (Bugs love to nest in the opening...)

Note that for emergency heating you can go through a tank of propane in a hurry.  There may be merit in buying your own 100 lb tank, and parking it next to your hookup.  You need a friend to horse it there, but it may be there for a LONG time before you need to refill it.

Also:  Here in Alberta, you can get an older tank recertified (Pressure test and a new valve) for much less than the new cost.  Not worth it for the barbecue size but for 40's and up it may be worth it.  Many propane dealers are set up to do this.

A final thought:  While $5 a gallon is too much, your project is going to save you only a hundred bucks a year, and the first year of that is gone to get your tanks.  Is it worth it?

Keep your tanks painted to stop rust.  Either aluminum or white.

Answer (score 1):

Technically you need a high pressure regulator at the tank and a low pressure regulator at the stove.  Tank pressure has to be regulated down so that your low pressure regulator can further reduce it to  11" water column pressure which is what the range needs to see.  If you try to feed the green regulator from the tank, you may blow it out particularly on a hot day when the tank pressure rises. I recommend you have a certified gas man check your installation to make sure it is safe, most will do it off the books night or weekend and charge you under $50 to check.

Answer (score 0):

First problem is that you are with Suburban.  They are worse than Comcast when it comes to customer support.  Also, $5.30 is way too much to pay for propane.  I pay $2.70.

If you are truly using only 40 gallons a year, you are correct to get smaller tank.  You can shop around your local Propane suppliers to get good deal.   One thing to consider is OWN the tank, shop around for the fuel.  This is not always the best deal, but it helps convince the suppliers that they are dealing with an informed buyer.  and since the price of propane follows that of gasoline, you will know when is good time to call around.

on the topic of available, ask the suppliers on your phone calls.  usually install is free and rental is free with annual purchase of one tankfull of gas.

good luck