# Can I use my 40 pound propane tank for my cooktop?

Tags: propane

I installed a propane cooktop, had the local propane company install a propane tank and outside.  turns out we do not use very much propane for cooking but they charge us a lot in rental and mandatory minimums.  I would like to have them take their tank back and hook it up to a 40 pound propane tank like what is used on my BBQ grill.  I can see the fittings are different and I can see the regulator is on the tank so I need a regulator. What sort of fittings, adapters, and regulators would I need to convert to a 40 pound propane tank?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How could I use 40lb Propane tanks in a residential hook up?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/24428/how-could-i-use-40lb-propane-tanks-in-a-residential-hook-up)

Comment: "Where can I get the fittings" falls under our product recommendation policy, so I'm editing that out. I don't believe the answers on the potential duplicate really cover what fittings, regulators, or other adapters you need to install to do this sort of conversion.